# WorkManager Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I used WorkManager version `android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-beta03`.I used this workmanager for uploading files to server with dynamic interval time using OneTimeWorker.

This is what I do. Hope you can check it and tell me where i were wrong and alternative way to fix it.

First, I make a work request

```
    OneTimeWorkRequest workRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorkRequest.class)
            .setInitialDelay(0), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addTag("UploadData")
            .build();

    WorkManager
            .getInstance()
            .getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(workRequest.getId())
            .observeForever(workInfoObserverBackground);
    WorkManager
            .getInstance()
            .enqueueUniqueWork("UploadData", ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, workRequest);
```

Then, Define Observer to listen to its result. I also start next run here.

```
workInfoObserverBackground = workInfo -> {
            if (workInfo != null){
                switch (workInfo.getState()) {
                    case SUCCEEDED:
                    case FAILURE:
                        WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(workRequest.getId()).removeObserver(workInfoObserverBackground);
                        WorkManager.getInstance().cancelUniqueWork("UploadData");
                        WorkManager.getInstance().cancelAllWorkByTag("UploadData");
                        workRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorkRequest.class)
                                .setInitialDelay(next_interval_time_received_from_api), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                .addTag("UploadData")
                                .build();
                        WorkManager
                                .getInstance()
                                .getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(workRequest.getId())
                                .observeForever(workInfoObserverBackground);
                        WorkManager
                                .getInstance()
                                .enqueueUniqueWork("UploadData", ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, workRequest);
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
```

After some minutes (i cannot record it, because it randomly happen) it crashed and this is stacktrace collected from logcat.

```
1-15 21:46:14.806 25964-26054/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-8-thread-1
Process: com.example.app, PID: 25964
android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. 
at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:108)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:139)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
at androidx.work.impl.model.WorkSpecDao_Impl.getInputsFromPrerequisites(WorkSpecDao_Impl.java:1112)
at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker(WorkerWrapper.java:171)
at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

My interval time is always 1 sec. Maybe old task hang with next task and cannot be destroy?